# Where I should declare a session variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, session-variables

I am building a Asp.net Application. I need to save a HashTable in a session.

At page load i am writing

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       Session["AttemptCount"]=new Hashtable(); //Because of this line.
    }   
}
```

Here problem is, when a user refresh the page, session["AttemptCount"] also get refreshed.
I want to know where should I declare

```
Session["AttemptCount"]=new Hashtable();
```

So that my seesion do not get refeshed.

**EDIT** In Global.asax, this session will get started, as soon as user opens the website. I want to creat this session only if user go to a particular page. i.e Login.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do it in the `Session_Start` method in your [Global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw.aspx) like so...

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["AttemptCount"]=new Hashtable();
}
```

**Update:**

Then simply just do a check to see if the session variable exists, if it doesn't only then create the variable. You could stick it in a property to make things cleaner like so...

```
public Hashtable AttemptCount
{
    get 
    {
        if (Session["AttemptCount"] == null)
            Session["AttemptCount"]=new Hashtable();
        return Session["AttemptCount"];
    }
}
```

And then you could just call on the property `AttemptCount` wherever you need like so...

```
public void doEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AttemptCount.Add("Key1", "Value1");
}
```

Comment: In Global.asax, this session will get started, as soon as user opens the website. I want to creat this session only if user go to a particular page. i.e Login.aspx

Comment: I've updated my answer, you'll simply need to check to see if it exists by checking against null

Comment: What do you store in the hashtable? Is it the number of times the user has attempted to login?

Comment: Yes, I am storing no. of attempts to login for a particular user. So if a particular user attempt to login, more than 15 times, I can block that session.

Comment: This will be very easy for people to get around by disabling session cookies.

Comment: I record log in failures in a database table with the date and time. If 5 failed log in attempts occur from the same IP address, I kick that IP address out for 15 minutes. Not foolproof, but anyone attempting to constantly log in will have to change their IP address to continue after 5 failed attempts within 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a property like this in your page:

```
protected Hashtable AttemptCount
{
  get
  {
    if (Session["AttemptCount"] == null)
      Session["AttemptCount"] = new Hashtable();
    return Session["AttemptCount"] as Hashtable; 
  }
}
```

then you can use it without having to worry:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.AttemptCount.Add("key", "value");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

test if it exists first

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       if(Session["AttemptCount"] == null)
       {
          Session["AttemptCount"]=new Hashtable(); //Because of this line.
       }
    }   
}
```

though the session_start is better, you only need to uses it on one page but you can create it for each session.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hashtable hastable_name=new Hashtable()
Session["AttemptCount"]=hastable_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Global.asax and the Application_Started (I think) and there is one for session started too.